# trouble with a search function

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, match

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.task = task;
    this.who = who;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.done = false;
}    

// more code that adds the todo objects to the page and to the array todos

function search() {
    for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        var todoObj = todos[i];
        console.log(todoObj.who); //shows both jane and scott
        console.log(todoObj.task); // shows both do something and get milk
    }
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").value;
    searchTerm = searchTerm.trim();
    var re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    var results = todoObj.who.match(re);
    if (searchTerm == null || searchTerm == "") {
        alert("Please enter a string to search for");
        return;
    } else {
        alert(results);
    }
}
```

This is a search function where I am trying to match what the user types into the search bar with objects that I have created earlier in the code. They must match the "who" and "task" parameters that I have given to the objects. So one object is who: jane task: do something and the other is who: scott task: get milk. The problem is, in my last alert I can only match scott and not jane. Scott is the last one I added. Is there some way I need to modify my loop or change my search criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looping through the items, but then using `todoObj` after that loop. So `todoObj` will just hold the last item in the array. You need to reorganize a little...try something like this:

```
function search() {
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").value;
    searchTerm = searchTerm.trim();

    if (searchTerm == null || searchTerm == "") {
        alert("Please enter a string to search for");
        return;
    } else {
        var todoObj = undefined,
            results = undefined,
            re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");

        for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
            todoObj = todos[i];
            results = todoObj.who.match(re);
            if (results) {
                alert("You found " + todoObj.who + ", who needs to " + todoObj.task + " by " + todoObj.dueDate);
                return;
            }
            console.log(re.lastIndex);
        }

        alert("You didn't match anyone");
    }
}
```

Here's an example of it working as I think you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/sHSdK/2/

Comment: Also, the creation of a new RegExp could be outside of the for-loop, I think

Comment: @albertoblaz Yeah, I noticed that. The one tricky thing with using `new RegExp` and not `/stuff/` is that it's weird with loops. I think I have to set the `lastIndex` property in the loop each time if I want to declare it once. I was looking that up and was planning on updating that :)

Comment: @albertoblaz Actually, I'm not sure if it's so much a difference between `new RegExp` and `/stuff/` as it is about being in a loop. Anyways, the fact that this function returns immediately after matching means it's not important here. But I think in other situations where they cache the regex before the loop and reuse every iteration, you need to set `re.lastIndex = 0;` immediately inside. Again, I _think_

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure as well. I guess in loops there would be no difference because `/stuff/` is just the literal way of creating a regular expression. It is the same case than `new Array()` vs `[]`. So... maybe you are creating a new object for each iteration with the literal too. Unfortunately, I don't know... :(

Comment: @albertoblaz Exactly. I don't know why I'm associating the problem only with `new RegExp`...maybe it's just been a coincidence that the places I've seen this discussed are always using `new RegExp`. I don't know, I'm trying reproduce the problem I'm talking about and I can't even do that!

Comment: @albertoblaz Ah! I think I realized what it was. The fact that `String.match` is used in this code means the regexp isn't affected. But when the regexp methods are used (like `.exec`, `.test`, etc.), then the `lastIndex` property is affected and needs reset if going to be used again that way. Maybe this helps explain it: http://jsfiddle.net/jHwhC/